# IE 10 - Unable to get property 'PageRequestManager' of undefined or null reference:

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, telerik

Telerik controls are not working fine with internet explorer 10 browser, i have changed the IE10 to compatibility mode it worked fine, i noticed that when loading the page i get JS error:

***Unable to get property 'PageRequestManager' of undefined or null reference:***

Any ideas/Suggestion would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Browser definition files that shipped with .NET 2.0 and .NET 4 may need to be updated. See the following Microsoft link for details and a [hotfix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600088).